# Why anode attracts Anions if anode is positively charged and anions are negatively charged

Tags: current, diodes

Why does anode attract anions if anode is positively charged while anions are negatively charged ? Same is with cathode ...cathode is negatively charged and attract positively charged cations ..why is it so?

Comment: just linking, just linking: http://www.av8n.com/physics/anode-cathode.htm

Comment: "like" charges repel, "unlike" charges attract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search for you and found this page

```
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29992/why-is-the-anode-positive-if-anions-are-negative
```

here is the answer by a member named clabacchio :

> In the diode, and specifically in the so-called depletion region, there is diffusion of carriers (electrons and holes) from one region to the other. Since the Anode is positively doped, it will attract electrons from the cathode, and this will cause the formation of Anions in its side of the depletion region.